# Weird Jade blocks overlap

Tags: javascript, express, pug, indentation

I'm using Jade as the Template Engine for my express app. I was setting up a header for the main page and added a blocks tag to the bottom of the layout file:

layout.jade

```
doctype 5
html
    head
        title= title
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')

    body
        div#header
            ul#mainNav
                li: a(href='/') Home 
            ul#personNav
                li: a(href='/login') Login/ Register 
    block content
```

And for index.jade I have this:

```
extends layout

block content
    div#mainBody
        p Hello
```

I'm trying to figure out why I have the hello paragraph tag inline with the header. This is what the output looks like.

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-wEBye5dTV0E/UhQ4pXDemZI/AAAAAAAAH4c/5FlY3PPw7_A/w968-h544-no/Screenshot+from+2013-08-20+23%3A44%3A23.png

Edit: I think this has a lot to do with the language seeing the block as part of the header. I don't know how to turn this off.

Edit 2: Sorry, Seems I forgot the styles. As you can see it's very light.

style.css

```
body
{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a
{
  color: #00b7ff;
}

#mainNav li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
    float: left;
}


#personNav li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type:none;
    float: right;
}

#mainBody
{
    margin: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Any style written for p and for the div with id mainBody tag?

Comment: any way to see your style.css ?

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Could you please provide a screenshot of your required view.

Comment: It is because of your style, it happened. Need to see the styles. A fiddle link will do.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham Well, I don't have a screen shot of my required view. I strictly want to have a header with a few links and a separate body directly underneath. It's just not doing that.

Comment: Looks like I figured it out. I needed to wrap the header in padding. I'm such a derp.

Comment: I am not having any issues in the view when I used your stylesheet.

Comment: Yeah, it was weird. It works how. Thanks for the help.